# How to implementing a user level access in yii?

Tags: yii

Is there a good extension for yii framework that controls user permissions. Give them different levels of access. I have checked some of them, they are good but up to date for example http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/rights/.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/auth perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You can look up this Yii extension. I used it a couple of times myself. http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/srbac/

Answer (score 0):

Before implementing an extention please checkout original rbac from yii. It is important to understand how it works. Extentions are mainly made to have an graphical administration for it.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#role-based-access-control